# My Java server program is not working

Tags: java, server

I post two codes here. but the first one is not working(no window would pop up), the second one is working. and I don't know why, can someone help me?  The only difference is in the main method and the constructor. thanks a lot.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Server extends JFrame
{
    //server components
    ServerSocket server;
    Socket socket;
    DataInputStream fromClient;
    DataOutputStream toClient;
    //JFrame components
    JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea(10, 50);

    public Server()
    {
        txtArea = new JTextArea(10, 50);
        add(txtArea);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        try
        {
            server = new ServerSocket(8000);
            txtArea.append("Server started at" + new Date() + "\n");
            while(true)
            {
                socket = server.accept();
                fromClient = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                toClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                double radius = fromClient.readDouble();
                double area = radius * radius * 3.1415926;
                toClient.writeDouble(area);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Server Connecting failed ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Server();
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Server extends JFrame
{
    //server components
    ServerSocket server;
    Socket socket;
    DataInputStream fromClient;
    DataOutputStream toClient;
    //JFrame components
    JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea(10, 50);

    public Server()
    {
        txtArea = new JTextArea(10, 50);
        add(txtArea);

        try
        {
            server = new ServerSocket(8000);
            txtArea.append("Server started at" + new Date() + "\n");
            while(true)
            {
                socket = server.accept();
                fromClient = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                toClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                double radius = fromClient.readDouble();
                double area = radius * radius * 3.1415926;
                toClient.writeDouble(area);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Server Connecting failed ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Server mainServer = new Server();

        mainServer.pack();
        mainServer.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainServer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainServer.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the differences between the two programs? What is the line about means that it works/doesn't?

Comment: @PeterLawrey second snippet calls the `pack`, `setLocationRelativeTo`, `setDefaultCloseOperationmethods` and `setVisible` methods, inherited from `JFrame`, in the `main` method instead of in the `Server` constructor.

Comment: @Arjan that's what I want to ask. thanks

Comment: The second snippet doesn't work because the statements in `main` below the declaration of `mainServer` are never reached.  It hangs on `Server mainServer = new Server();` Aside from the question what's gonna terminate your `while(true)` loop..., the `socket = server.accept();` in the ctor seems to make the program hang as well.  The `accept()` method: *Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The method blocks until a connection is made.*  Anything ever making a connection to this server?

Comment: @Arjan I assume you mean the first one is not working. I wrote a simple client program to connect to it. it works well with the second but not the first one. and I think I got your point: it never reached those methods(pack()...). thanks !